# derived class of a base class functioning as an abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I have defined a super class `element`. There are some derived class of `element` say `triangle` , `quad`  and `cube`.  Some of the `element` objects are boundary element. If the `element` is boundary element, then I have to define additional data members and functions. I could have easily derive a `boundary_element` class if the `element` class is not  base class.(What I meant is, if `triangle` , `quad` and `cube` are separate classes I can define separate derived classes like `boundary_triangle` , `boundary_quad` , and`boundary_cube`).

So my problem is I have to define a subclass `boundary_element` which has to be the base (or even abstract) class for defining derived classes `boundary_quad` , `boundary_triangle` and `boundary_cube`.

Is this somehow possible in C++? could anyone suggest any architecture which serves the purpose?

Another way I can solve my problem according to my logic is, define a class like below:

```
class boundary_element
{    
    element* m_boundary_elem;  
    //data members needed for quad,triangle and cube
    public:
    boundary (element*);
    //functions for modifying data's of triangle,cube,quad.

}
```

The `element` pointer is defined as member variable of another class.  How do I restructure this class effectively using inheritance. ( i.e Function it as an abstract class, for deriving `boundary_triangle` , `boundary_quad`, and `boundary_cube`  class )

I don't know my question is weird but as a beginner I'm really confused how to use inheritance properly. Sorry if my heading is misleading.

Comment: I guess you just shouldn't use inheritance for this problem at all.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, then I have to define too much redundant data types and functions in one class. Will it be inefficient since it consume large memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has multiple inheritance, so you can derive from `Element` and `Boundary` at the same time and avoid code duplication.

Something like this:

```
class Element {
};

class Boundary {
};

class Triangle : public Element {
};

class BoundaryTriangle : public Triangle, public Boundary {
};

. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this somehow possible in C++?

Of course it is.

> could anyone suggest any architecture which serves the purpose?

Something along these lines:

- Have an abstract base class and interface

  ```
  class AbstractShape {
       boundary getBoundary() const = 0;
       void draw(OutputScreen& screen) const = 0;
  };
  ```
- Have implementations for particular shapes like

  ```
  Triangle : public AbstractShape {
      // Implement the triangle specifics   
  };

  Rectangle : public AbstractShape {
      // Implement the rectangle specifics   
  };

  Circle : public AbstractShape {
      // Implement the circle specifics   
  };
  ```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. A shape can be in boundary. If it is boundary, then how do I define boundary_triangle, boundary_rectangle,and boundary_circle, in such a way it inherits some of common data and functions from a base boundary_element class?

Comment: @user7491077 You are probably approaching the problem wrong, otherwise I completely misunderstood what you're trying to do.